# CLI Features not working when switching to another user

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

If I am the root user then I have a few CLI features like autocompletion and I can press arrow up to go through a list of the last executed commands and so on.

However, I created a user named **foo** with this command `useradd -g www-data -d /srv/www/vhosts/foo/ foo`

Then I switched to it `sudo su foo`

For this user the above mentioned features do not work. If I press tab for autocompleting, then it just inserts a tab. If I click arrow up, then it inserts `^[[A`

[image]

Comment: I can only think of a different shell for root and this user. What does `echo $SHELL` return for both of them?

Comment: Nice, thanks for the hint. They are different. I get `/bin/sh` for the user *foo* and `/bin/bash` for the root user.

Comment: Yeah you didn't explicitly supply a shell via the useradd `-s` switch - is there a shell specified in `/etc/default/useradd`? if so what is is?

Comment: @steeldriver, I see. In useradd the shell is set to /bin/sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user `foo` has a limited shell as indicated by your replies. You can fix it by:

```bsh
(sudo) usermod --shell /bin/bash foo
```